# How to proprly write string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this bit jQuery with HTML. Unfortunately its not working correctly. Can anyone please advice how it should be please?

```
var Bred =("<div class='TakeMeTo' style='width:" + width + "px; right: " + width + "'>" + whereTo + "</div>");
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not working correctly". What exactly is happening? Whatever the case, you're usually better off constructing dynamic HTML this way:

```
var Bred = $("<div></div>").addClass("TakeMeTo")
  .css("width", width + "px").css("right", width)
  .text(whereTo);
```

Use `css()` instead of directly setting the `style` attribute. Optionally you may wish to use `.html(whereTo)` instead, whichever is appropriate.

Why do it this way? Things will be correctly escaped.

Comment: This is my result from string I written above

<div class="TakeMeTo" style="width: 91px;">Some function</div>

missing right in css

Answer (score 1):

I think I found he root of your problem

you need to specify a px unit for the "right" css property, like below:

```
 var Bred =("<div class='TakeMeTo' style='width:" + width + "px; right: " + width + "px;'>" + whereTo + "</div>");
```

Notice the second [ "px;'>" ] after [ right: " + width + ]

Answer (score 0):

This one works nice. Thanks you all for suggestions

```
var Bred = $("<div></div>").attr("class", "TakeMeTo").attr("style", "width:" + width + "px; right: " +  width  + "px").text(whereTo);
```